# Exchange 2010 won't allow IMAP connections over PlainText authentication

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, imap

I have IMAP enabled for the server, the IMAP4 service running, and IMAP enabled for the account. This is Exchange 2010 server. Emails work fine, but when I try to login over IMAP I get the following error:

> NO LOGIN failed.

When I run IMAP Test I get the following:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>test-imapconnectivity -Connect Plaintext -MailboxCredential:(Get-Credential) | fl

cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Credential


RunspaceId                  : d70e56b0-0bd2-4ebe-954f-238ef373e43b
LocalSite                   : Default-First-Site-Name
SecureAccess                : False
VirtualDirectoryName        :
Url                         :
UrlType                     : Unknown
Port                        : 143
ConnectionType              : Plaintext
ClientAccessServerShortName : SERVER
LocalSiteShortName          : Default-First-Site-Name
ClientAccessServer          : SERVER.FE.local
Scenario                    : Test IMAP4 Connectivity
ScenarioDescription         : Connect to server using IMAP4 protocol, search for the test message, and delete it along
                              with any messages that are older than 24 hours.
PerformanceCounterName      : ImapConnectivity-Latency
Result                      : Failure
Error                       : IMAP Error: aIFX NO LOGIN failed.

UserName                    : sanctuary
StartTime                   : 09/08/2020 4:39:11 PM
Latency                     : 00:00:00.2731055
EventType                   : Error
LatencyInMillisecondsString :
Identity                    :
IsValid                     : True
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the login type of the IMAP protocol in your Exchange Server? You could run the command `Get-ImapSetting | fl LoginType` to check it:

[image]

Did you do the imap connectivity test with an admin credential? Based on my test, if we run the above command with an admin credential, we will get an "**Error**" `IMAP Error: aXXX NO LOGIN failed`, at the same time, we couldn't perform an IMAP connection for an admin mailbox.

If you failed to pass the imap test with credential of a normal user mailbox, try to run the command `Set-ImapSettings -LoginType 3` to switch the login type to **SecureLogin**, then restart **Microsoft Exchange IMAP** service and configure an IMAP account for this user.
(Here is an article about configure for your reference: **[Exchange Best Practices: Secure POP and IMAP Access](https://practical365.com/exchange-server/exchange-best-practices-secure-pop-and-imap-access/)**)